# Climate in an hypothetical Planet

Tags: biology, society, planets, physics, climate

Let there be absolutely none, exactly 0 axial tilt. Let the earth's orbit around the sun be a perfect circle with 0 eccentricity and a surface to surface ( constant) radius equal to the harmonic mean of the surface to surface earth to sun distance through the past 800 years(an integral if time is thought to be continuous or measuring the distance every quantum, least increment of time, for 800 years). Let the sun be a perfect sphere and the earth be a perfect sphere(no mountains, cliffs, valeys, deeps) too. Let the angular speeds of earths movements(Revolution, Orbit, etc) be ever constant(a day of 24 hours and a Year of 360 days). 
Let the consistancy of the Earth to the core be perfectly uniform with a perfectly uniform surface(allowing the exception for an amount of rivers running through perfectly straight lines of longitudes with a symmetric distribution between the latitudes so the human civilisation could have water and thrive). Let the consistancy of the rivers/ocean and atmosphere be perfectly uniform with a breathable partial pressure and a tolerable total pressure.

I tried to make the climate as uniform as possible and not simply remove Milankovitch Cycles. I do not have any ideas how the climate could be more uniform if anyone has any ideas I would be happy to think about them.

Now to my question

**How will Earth's climate be and how will that climate affect human life and civilisation?**

I think that the poles will shrink as there would not be any winter, the variance would be minimal and largely due to longitude difference rather than to latitude differences (proximity to the rivers could play a minor roles), the average temperature would increase, as less heat will be radiated back to outer space and more of it kept on earth (Radiation of Black Body). I want my hypotheses confirmed and a way to imagine how the climate would be.  As for the consequences to life and civilisation I have no ideas.

N.B I tried to ask a similar question on Earth.Sciences because I thought it belonged to climatology and planetary science but they refered me to worldbuilding.

Comment: Life never evolves because you've stripped too many irregularities which help its evolution. You've neglected a moon, which is a major factor, and the entire planet has one biome, which sounds like a good thing, but completely isn't because of the lack of diversity, which, for instance, means a single disease on a crop wipes out everyone, as only one kind of crop would develop.

Comment: Look at Jupiter: You get an atmosphere with a distinct band structure, very strong and longlived storm systems, and plenty of ordinary turbulence. And the band structure means: Distinct climate zones, and pretty cold poles.

Comment: @Karl I do not know what band stucture precisely means. Does it mean that there are layers with uniform consistency within them but between one another the consistency is not uniform? I meant a whole atmosphere that has a single uniform consistency between all latitudes, all longitudes and all altitudes up to the Thermosphere. Each and every small ml of Atmospheric air should have the exact same consistency.

Comment: @Karl I required an uniform atmosphere so more than a single band would not be compatible.

Comment: Take the height difference between the highest and lowest point on Earth, Mount Everest and Challenger's deep. Calculate its ratio to the Earth radius. Earth is way more spherical than you think.

Comment: @L.Dutch It has no (constant) radius it is an Ellipsoid( Tri.axial, skalene). It is not a ball(the entire volume included in a sphere). Do you want to take the median/ half of the distance between the poles or between some points in the equator? I would be much more confortable with the ratio of distances of the highest and lowest Points to the center of volume( not accounting for density, or gravitational field) of the Earth.

Comment: I’m sorry but this is quite a broad question. The answer to “How will Earth's climate be and how will that climate affect human life and civilisation“ will be an encyclopedia. I strongly suggest you focus on one aspect at a time. Please refer your question to [the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions/).

Comment: And just to note everything would die if it ever evolved at all. Nothing will propagate and all water will pool at the equator, then stagnate.

Comment: @VogonPoet why would the water pool at the equator? And what does propagate mean? Do you mean genetically? Nothing will Reproduce? Why is that?

Comment: Because you made the earth a sphere, the poles have zero centripetal force and the equator has maximum centripetal force. At the poles, water is only pulled by gravity. As you approach the equator from either side, water is being “flung” off (so it is lighter). Heavier water will flow into the lighter water areas. Everyone above 10° latitude will be in permanent drought. Everyone below will be submerged. Earth is an oblate spheroid to offset these forces.

Comment: Evolution uses storms, earthquakes, and tectonic shifts to isolate pockets of genetic ecosystems. It’s like parallel processing. Take a horse, put it on 10 different islands, and each one evolves slightly differently creating the diversity needed to survive endangering events. Storms are essential to many species for propagation. Plant seeds, bird and insect species, find new homes only by storms. This way they can’t be easily wiped out in one spot.

Comment: Try this messy experiment: paint a pool ball or some other heavy ball with watercolor. Put it on a newspaper and spin it. Watch where all the paint goes.

Comment: @VogonPoet But evolution is the effect not the cause. Storms and Earthquakes are the same endangering events that the new species will survive. It is simply a deterministic effect. The DNA propagates itself. Mutations occur. If it happens that this mutations are beneficial or neutral they will remain if they are hazardous the speciment will not reproduce. Evolution is a matter of probability and not cause. I think centripetal force is inversely proportional to the radius. So the maximal centripetal force would be at the poles not the equator.

Comment: DNA does not propagate itself, nature takes the path of least resistance. Environmental pressure migrates DNA. Horses do not travel hundreds of miles for new pastures when the grass beneath their feet is lush and green. The drought or pestilence forces migration.

Comment: @VogonPoet I did not say the contrary. Probably I used the wrong word maybe replicate would be more suitable. But evolution just happens it is not that something causes evolution. A fire burns the grass so the giraffes that have a long neck can feed so their DNA replicates while their short necked peers' DNA does not. It was not that the fire caused the mutation. It killed(it created the necessary conditions to starve) the short necked giraffes. Evolution is not caused it happens and Natural selection is just a matter of Acidents and Probability.

Answer (score 0):

No moon to stabilize the planetary axis of rotation .. AND "pull on the hand brake" .. so the day length would come close to 6 to 8 hours - which in turn propels wind speeds to some hundred km / h on "not so windy" days and easily over 1000 km/h on stormy days ...

IF any life would form - it would be very flat.

The lack of the moon has another "after effect" - thesis never collided with your version of earth, meaning the cores of both proto-planets wouldn't unite. Your theoretical earth would be solid in a few hundred million years after it formed. - Now for a small experiment try rolling around a cooked egg vs a fresh egg. 
Your earth would spin even faster after the core and mantle solidify. All this would lead to a terrible weather.
Your earth would lack tectonics bring enough green house gas into the athmosphere = once the core and mantle solidify your earth would turn into a iceball, provided your version of the solar system allowed your earth to collect enough comets and asteroids to deliver the water. 
Once cold, there is nothing that can help your planet.

You have a deeply frozen planet, with heavy storms about all the time, instable rotational axis - which would "skip" around at random time spans (our axis slowly rotates over ~ 26000 yrs stabilized by the moon) - the athmosphere of your planet was never "cleaned" of Ammonia and methane and other more toxic gas....
The constant skipping of the planetary axis would make it impossible for any climate zones to form - in principle you have pure (COLD) chaos as climate

Comment: Is a carefully placed moon incompatible with the lack milankovitch cycles? Are we in a dillemma between milankovitch planets or moon?

Comment: I did not understand "The lack of the moon has another "after effect" - thesis never collided with your version of earth, meaning the cores of both proto-planets wouldn't unite." Particularly  "after effect" - thesis never collided.  Who didn't collide with my version of earth? Thesis is the subject of the verb to collide with?Your earth would lack tectonics bring enough green house gas? Did you forget a to between tectonics and bring. I am more comfortable with an to + infinitive.

Comment: Is a clean atmosphere incompatible with a perfectly uniform one?

Comment: As for lack maybe substitute adbsence if anything for idiomaticity. As someone who speaks English as a Foreign Language I am quite punctilious and verbose and less idiomatic.